# building a basic search bar Material-UI

Tags: material-ui

I want to build a really basic search bar with a search icon (similar to the one on `Material-UI` ) & invoke a function with the current value of the search field whenever the user hits enter or click on the search enter. I am new to `Material-UI` & I'm struggling to find my way through the different text fields elements.

I currently have this code

```
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';

class ...somecode
...somecode
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      resources: [],
      value: '',
    };
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  search(/* access value upons enter/ search icon click */) { <--------------------------
  }
...some code
return (
  <form id="search">
    <Input type="text" value={value} onChange={(event) => { this.handleChange(event); }} placeholder="Search..." autoFocus fullWidth />
  </form>
);
```

p.s: I had a really hard time fiddling around with all the APIs and options available in the input suite (I highly suggest an explanation of how they are related in the docs)

Comment: Can you please show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Alright. I'll edit the answer to reflect what I currently have...